# windows phone 8 sharing an image along with a prepopulated text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, social-networking

I've created an app for windows phone 8 in c#. 
When a button is pressed i take a screenshot and share it with the social networks, i want to share along the image a prepopulated text in the status textbox, but when i try with the code below it only shares the image, am i doing something wrong?

```
private void Share_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(this.theGraph1, null);
        var width = (int)bmp.PixelWidth;
        var height = (int)bmp.PixelHeight;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(width * height * 4))
        {
            bmp.SaveJpeg(ms, width, height, 0, 100);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var lib = new MediaLibrary();
            var picture = lib.SavePicture(string.Format("test.jpg"), ms);
            var text = new ShareStatusTask();
            var task = new ShareMediaTask();
            text.Status = AppResources.ShareThought;
            task.FilePath = picture.GetPath();
            task.Show();
            text.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combine ShareStatusTask and ShareMediaTask into a single share "action". The is no way to share text + image using a standard way in WP8, but you can do it in WP8.1, tak a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871374.aspx